# Module not found when importing package

Tags: python, import

Even after googling, trying a million things etc, I just can't get package importing to work properly. I have a simple folder structure like this:

```
(main folder)
                     ---------------
funktio (folder)---->| __init__.py |
main.py              | tulosta.py  |
country_data.py      ---------------
```

Basically I'm trying to import tulosta.py into main.py. Tulosta.py has a function that prints certain stuff from country_data.py. So far the program works when I paste the contents of tulosta.py into main.py and scrap the import of tulosta.py from main.py (so the script reads from country_data properly). I'm doing a school assignment and it requires importing a module and a package. My problem is, if I try to

```
import funktio.tulosta
```

I only get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Kouluhommelit\Script-programming\moduuliharkka\main.py", line 4, in <module>
tulosta.tulosta()
NameError: name 'tulosta' is not defined
```

and if I try to put "from tulosta import tulosta" into the init file, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Kouluhommelit\Script-programming\moduuliharkka\main.py", line 1, in <module>
import funktio.tulosta
File "E:\Kouluhommelit\Script-programming\moduuliharkka\funktio\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from tulosta import tulosta
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tulosta'
```

So basically whatever I try I get an error code. Here's the code from main.py:

```
import funktio.tulosta
import country_data

tulosta.tulosta()
```

and tulosta.py:

```
def tulosta():
    for code in country_data.countrycodes:
            print (country_data.codemap[code], ':\n\t','Head honcho:', country_data.countries[country_data.codemap[code]]['head honcho'],'\n\t','Population:', country_data.countries[country_data.codemap[code]]['population'],'million')
```

I'm really getting desperate after struggling with this for 4+ hours already. It seems like such a simple operation, but apparently it isn't. Please help. I'll provide more info if needed.

Here's the assignment:

```
Rearrange the code from previous exercises:

Make a folder called "moduuliharkka"
Make a python file called "country_data" where you put the lists and dicts from the exercise 15.
Then make a new folder inside the moduuliharkka-folder called "funktio" (tip: init)
Put the code from exercise 16. inside a function and save it as a .py file in the funktio-folder
Go back to your moduuliharkka-folder, make a main.py file where you import the country_data module and the funktio folder as a package
Call the function imported in the main.py script
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make one extra call in your main file. Currently, you have imported the file `tulosta` from `funktio`, however, you need to access the function/class/variable in that file. `tulosta.tulosta()` is not including the folder name, which is still needed
In main:

```
import funktio.tulosta
functio.tulosta.tulosta() #call the function in "tulosta" here
```

If you do want to call `tulosta()` as `tulosta.tulosta()`, import with an alias:

```
import funktio.tulosta as tulosta
tulosta.tulosta()
```

Comment: @PaulCornelius just edited my post. OP commented about importing `country_data` in `funktio` spurring me to mention that he had to import `country_data` into `funktio` but since deleted his comment.